# How can I run "apt-get install" in the background?

Tags: apt

When I try to install a package, for instance *nsnake*, with the command  `sudo apt-get install nsnake &`, the process immediately stops. I can bring it to the foreground and enter my sudo password, pause it (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>), and send it back to the background again. But then the shell will immediately pause the process, e.g.,

```
katriel@caseylaptop:~$ bg     
[2]+ sudo apt-get install nsnake &   
[2]+  Stopped                 sudo apt-get install nsnake
```

Is it possible to install packages in the background? I may want to do this while installing large packages on a computer I'm SSH'ing into.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, sure.

Perform your `apt-get` command *with* fancy things around it

```
sudo bash -c 'apt-get -y install guake >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown'
```

Part explanation:

- The `sudo bash -c` part spawns a new `bash` process, and runs `apt-get -y install guake >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown` inside that new shell.
- These commands are then run inside the new subshell:

  - `apt-get -y install guake`: The main apt-get command you want to run.

    - `>/dev/null 2>&1` pipes stdout and stderr to /dev/null.
  - `& disown` disowns the preceding job and exits the subshell.

Comment: Is "yes |" needed when you use the -y switch?

Comment: @user31389: Not strictly, but it may help if a package has further prompts during installation.

Comment: Would be really nice to understand why this works (and why it is necessary).

Comment: @katriel: It's not that easy to explain. I've attempted an explanation in my answer, though.

Comment: @minerz029, thanks for the detail. I'm still not quite sure I understand why the shell won't run apt-get install in the background in the first place-- as I commented below it doesn't seem to be only a sudo authorization or Y/n prompt issue.

Comment: @katriel: It's because Ctrl+Z **pauses** the command, meaning it is paused (temporarily stopped).

Comment: Well, this runs but it doesn't seem to be running in the background--in the sense that it is still printing to stdout. In fact, if I take out the <code> yes | </code>, it throws some errors.

Comment: @katriel: See the edited answer.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks @minerz029! I am not sure your braces are in the right place, but in the end the command `sudo sh -c 'apt-get -y install nsnake >/dev/null' & disown` worked for me.

Comment: This answer would be complete with an explanation of the braces. I ran into trouble with them ('yes' not found, etc.).

Comment: @katriel: Fixed it up. The important part is that & disown should be in the quotes.

Comment: @minerz029. Actually that doesn't work for me, error `sh: 1: disown not found`. But with `& disown` out of the quotes it works quite well, if doing something different than you intended.

Comment: Furthermore `sudo apt-get -y install nsnake >/dev/null &` works, too.

Comment: @katriel: Use bash, then.

Answer (score 17):

I always like to use [screen](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/a-quick-tutorial-on-screen/) to run programs in the background.

Comment: +1 for screen. It's easy to use and great for background programs you want to access from time to time, like an irc client or as a substitute for multiple ssh connections when you need to quickly access a set of paths or files repeatedly

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: i prefer [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) to screen.

Answer (score 9):

Add the ampersand `&` to run *any* program and return to the prompt while the program runs, such as

```
sudo apt-get -y install nsnake &
```

You may get certain events and notifications popping up periodically in the shell, however. To hide these events, pipe them to STDOUT

```
sudo apt-get -y install nsnake >/dev/null &
```

Comment: The events were the problem. The solution seems to be to pipe them to STDOUT.

Answer (score -1):

It's a workaround, but first run anything with sudo, e.g. `sudo ls`. Your sudo authorization will be remembered for a while. Then you can just run `sudo apt-get -y install nsnake &` and you won't be asked for a password second time (unless some time has passed and authorization has expired).

Comment: You still need to type y at the prompt, which your commant wont let you do.

Comment: @minerz029 Oh, right. Fixed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure neither the sudo authorization nor the "Y/n" prompt that's interfering, since I don't have to do either if I bring the job to the foreground.