# How to put "sudo apt upgrade" on terminal background

Tags: command-line, 20.04

I ran:

```
sudo apt upgrade &
```

It asked me to tap "Y". After I tap "Y", it stops.

Comment: You have tagged a development release scheduled for release in 2020-April (thus 20.04). Development releases are off-topic on this site until released, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic but are supported on IRC or Ubuntu Forums.  Did you press <enter> after *tapping* Y?

Comment: **Voting to reopen:** Although OP tagged the question with +1 release but the question itself isn't really release specific. However, the question can be considered as dupe of [How can I run “apt-get install” in the background?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421807/how-can-i-run-apt-get-install-in-the-background)

Answer (score 3):

You can always use -y flag to avoid this.

```
sudo apt upgrade -y
```